# Should I say "I will come 'on' / 'in' / 'at' the time"?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, in-on-at

Which of the following options is the correct one?

1. > I will come '**on**' the time
2. > I will come '**in**' the time
3. > I will come '**at**' the time

The context is:

> **My friend**: Dory please tomorrow be at the station bus at 10:00 o'clock
>   **Me**: I will come [on?] the time, no problem.

Comment: In order for us to help you, we need to know the context: what is the exact scenario you are trying to express? The phrases *on time* and *in time* are different from each other, and both are different from *at the time* and *at a time*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"I will come on time." - this is idiomatic.

"I will come at the time indicated." (which is 10:00 sharp) - this is very specific time-wise, you'll arrive on the dot - 10 o'clock sharp.

"I will come in time." (there's a time limit and you'll arrive within that acceptable time limit) - earlier than 10:00 or 10:00 sharp. (NOTE: provides indefinite length of time when used in a different context, i.e., Justice will come in time)

Just say that you'll come on time. That should suffice.

Answer (score 1):

"I will come at (and state the time)"
I speak English as my first language

Comment: Hi David, and welcome to ELL! As we're all here to help learners, we'd appreciate if you explain your answer, so that the learner and the future readers would benefit from your knowledge.